# How to specify the previous page for browser back button

Tags: javascript, html, web.py

I am creating a web application.

I have a landing page which the user sees after logging in.

From the landing page they can click a link to go to detail page.

The detail page loads data for the default id to start with. It also contains a drop down for user to pick a different id. When user presses submit button it makes a get request to the same page, but uses the optional argument `id=someID` this reloads the page and shows the data for the newly selected id. All of this is working correctly.

My question is, if user chooses a few different ids from the drop down and clicks submit to view their data, now if he wants to get back to landing he has to go back through each id that he viewed. I would like to know if it is possible to set it up so that when they press back button they will go directly to landing page no matter how many times they've chosen new id's to view data for.

Here is the flow I'd like to achieve:

`/landing -> /detail -> /detail?id=1 -> /detail?id=2 -> [press back button] -> /landing`

Comment: Maybe you can create a link on the page which points to the landing page.

Comment: @SheikhHeera I could make a link that points to the landing page, but If possible I'd like to be able to simplify it for the user by making the back button go to the landing page. If it is not possible to make back button work how I want then I'll use a hardcoded link back to landing

Comment: Maybe you can use html5 history api to push landing page on each detail page.

Comment: I think you use [HTML5 history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to modify the `history` to maintain the back state, just like jcubic said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the requests on the details page pulled in via ajax. You have to do some refactoring so that on a successful request, the information it receives will repopulate like a content block, but this will allow the information on the details page to update without you actually navigating to a new page. Then it'll leave you the ability to press the back button to go back to the landing page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using a way to catch the amount of id's requested:

```
<INPUT Type="button" id="back" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-"number of id requests");return true;">
```